# Como bloquear um Pivot?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

No Windows Phone, temos a estrutura Pivot, que possuí os PivotItens, que são abas(telas) na qual o usuário navegar apenas deslizando o dedo para esquerda ou direita.

Estou fazendo um app e acompanhando o design do Windows 10, com menu hambúrguer, cheguei em uma tela na qual deveria ter um pivot, porém não quero a ação de deslizar para navegar entre os pivots, pois meu menu hambúrger é aberto com o deslizamento para direita. Quero saber se há como bloquear a ação deslize do Pivot, e deixar apenas o Click nos seus títulos?

Meu código do Pivot:

```
    <Grid Name="piv01" Margin="0,-50,0,0" Width="480" Height="645" Grid.Row="1">
        <CheckBox x:Name="online" Content="Desejo fazer o cadastro online." Checked="online_Checked" Unchecked="online_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="descricao" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Para isso será necessário enviar um e-mail com seus dados para realizarmos o cadastro. Seus dados NÃO serão usados para outro propósito." VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,85,20,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="nome" HorizontalAlignment="Right" InputScope="Default" KeyUp="nome_KeyUp" Tap="text_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Margin="0,160,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="cpf" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  InputScope="Number" KeyUp="nome_KeyUp" Tap="text_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Margin="0,220,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Right" InputScope="Default" KeyUp="nome_KeyUp" Tap="text_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Margin="0,280,10,0"/>
        <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="nasc" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,340,10,0" Width="285"/>
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="ocupa"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" InputScope="Default" KeyUp="nome_KeyUp" Tap="text_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,400,10,0" Width="285">
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
        <Button x:Name="go" Content="Pronto" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="go_Click" Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tNome" Text="Nome Completo:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,190,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tCPF" Text="CPF:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,250,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tEmail" Text="Email:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,310,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tNasc" Text="Data de Nascimento:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,370,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tOcupa" Text="Ocupação:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,430,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>

<phone:PivotItem AllowDrop="False">
    <phone:PivotItem.Header>
        <Image Source="/icoTiles.png"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Header>

    <Grid Name="piv02" Margin="0,-50,0,0" Width="480" Height="645" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="completa" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Você completou todas as etapas!" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Margin="0,80,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="tNormal"  Tap="tNormal_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Assets/tNormal.jpg" Width="308" Height="147" Margin="0,180,0,0"/>
        <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="308" Height="147" Margin="0,360,0,0">
            <Image x:Name="tTrans" Tap="tTrans_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Assets/tTrans.png" Width="308" Height="147" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock x:Name="isPhoto" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Você será levado a uma tela para selecionar sua imagem." VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,65,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="myPhoto" Content="Usar minha foto" Checked="myPhoto_Checked" Unchecked="myPhoto_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Selecione a tile desejada:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Margin="0,140,0,0"/>

    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não cheguei a testar, mas encontrei algo que deve ser o que voce procura no Stack em Inglês, usando a propriedade IsLocked:

```
<phone:Pivot IsLocked="True">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Foo">
        <TextBox />
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem Content="Bar" Header="Bar" />
    <phone:PivotItem Content="Baz" Header="Baz" />
</phone:Pivot>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572243/1509954

Abraços